# Views PDF Change Table Layout Setting

Tags: views, files

I am using **[Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf)** Module in my project.

This module provide only limited settings for table layout i want to generate pdf according to custom design as given below:

[image]

The pdf file generated through **views PDf module** currently as below:

[image]

so, please tell me how to design my pdf table in Views PDF Module.

Answer (score 2):

I done this before using global text field and html. Add all needed fields into view and exclude them from display. Then create an html layout using field replacement patterns according to your requirement using a **Global:Text** field. Then generate **PDF**.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: you have any working url for this or any demo link. please share

Comment: @KamalOberoi I dont have any sharable URLs. My requirement was to create  a formatted pdf with 5 images and details of content type.

Comment: it's ok. i am trying some other thing may be it's done.